# Unable to parse a specific text in HTML with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse the rating I have provided to a movie on IMDB. Below is my code:

```
with Session() as s:
    shaw = s.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/')
    shaw_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(shaw.content, 'html.parser')
    title_block = shaw_soup.find(class_ = 'title_block')
    rating_widget = title_block.find('div', id = 'star-rating-widget')
    star_rating_value = rating_widget.find('span', class_ = 'star-rating-value')
    print(star_rating_value)
```

The html structure of the portion of webpage is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0WH4.png)

The output of the print(star_rating_value) is None.
The curious part is when I am parsing other attributes, there is no issue. This issue is only for parsing the rating which I have provided to a movie.

Comment: The rating is loaded dynamically into the DOM thus `('span', class_ = 'star-rating-value')` is `null`. Can you get the rating from https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ratings (you can check whether it's loaded dynamically - i.e. using JavaScript - by turning off JavaScript in your Browser's Developer Tools settings)?

Comment: Thanks Gregor for your response! I tried to get the rating from the web page you mentioned. However, same issue happened again. I could not get the rating value. Some how it appeared to be null on parsed text. What might be the reason for this? Another thing, is there any other library in Python that is best suited for this? Shall I try Selenium?